# iPhone calendar error edit?usp=drive_web when opening attachment

Tags: iphone

When I attempt to open a file attached to an appointment in Calendar on my iPhone it has replaced the file name with and error, "edit?usp=drive_web" and the application crashes when the attachment is clicked. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If this is a shared calendar, this means that either the attachment has since been removed or that you do not have sufficient privileges to access it on your iPhone.

Comment: it is shared, but I have checked both of those features with the owner of the material and the attachment still won't appear :(